# Can i get the drawText(text) value and print it to Toast.makeText(text)

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

It is possible to get the value of text on

```
 public String drawText(
      final Canvas canvas, final float posX, final float posY, final String text, Paint bgPaint) {

float width = exteriorPaint.measureText(text);
float textSize = exteriorPaint.getTextSize();
Paint paint = new Paint(bgPaint);
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
//paint.setAlpha(160);
canvas.drawRect(posX, (posY + (int) (textSize) + overlap), (posX + (int) (width) + 2*overlap), posY, paint);

//VALUE ARE HERE
canvas.drawText(text, posX + overlap, (posY + textSize), interiorPaint);}
```

The problem is I want to get the value of text and use it to Toast.maketext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the following method to show toast from drawText method.

//Here pass your Application-level Context,

```
Toast.makeText(App.getInstant(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

See this [link](https://www.mobomo.com/2011/05/how-to-use-application-object-of-android/) for creating static instant to fetch application context